# How to see if my android device used yesterday

Tags: android, security, mobile, device

I forgot my phone to work(it was powered off-empty battery).So i want to know if there is way to see if someone enabled it and used it.
Any advice would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the forum to ask this. Stack Overflow is a site for computer programming questions. I would suggest asking your question over at https://android.stackexchange.com/